# why I can't use the PhantomJs in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

```
sudo apt-get install selenium
sudo apt-get install phantomjs
```

I intall the selenium and phantomjs under ubuntu 16.04. But when

> from selenium import webdriver
>
> browser = webdrive.PhantomJs()

Python Interpreter gives the error msg, **AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PhantomJs'.** I dont't know what goes wrong. Can anyone give some advice. I will be very grateful for that.

Comment: you missed the last letter of `webdriver` when calling PhantomJS()

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu will automatically install selenium for python2 you should install phantomjs for py3 using this command

sudo pip3 install -U selenium

And make sure when you run your script to specify Python interpreter version 3